# Fit image following JInternalFrame size

Tags: java, image, swing, jinternalframe

Is there any possible way to fitting size of an image following the size of Internal Frame?
I need to fit an image with 1600x900 px size into 900x600 JInternalFrame

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int width = dim.width;
    int height = dim.height;
    System.out.println("width = "+width);
    System.out.println("height = "+height);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(this.name.equals("")){
      g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("someimage")).getImage(),0,0,width,height,this);
    } else {
       //some method
    }
```

Comment: You'd scale it down, possibly add margins to avoid excess distortion, since the aspect ratios differ.

Comment: frankly, i tried to do "fitting size" in Desktop Pane, it's work fine. But in Internal Frame didn't